# Android Development : File is probably compressed

Tags: java, android

this'll be my first post on SO so please be gentle. I'm currently developing an Android app and am attempting to simply read a .txt file in. After many seperate hurdles to overcome (this is my first attempt at reading in a text file) I've come across a rather nasty problem of it throwing the error message

This file cannot be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed.

```
assetmgr = thiscontext.getAssets();
try {
    descriptor = assetmgr.openFd("level1.txt");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above piece of code is simply attempting to read in the text file. However, it is returning null to descriptor which is obviously causing errors further down the line.

```
inputStream = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
```

This is the line that is initialising the inputstream for parsing the text file in the loop I've created out of this scope.

So my problem is how do I fix the txt file not opening correctly and apprarently being compressed.

If I have made any errors in posting please let me know so I can correct them to get the best possible advice!

Cheers!

Comment: where did you put this level1.txt file?

Comment: Hi there @wtsang02. I've put the file in the assets folder. So for me personally it'd be AndroidDevelopment/crisis/assets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my problem is how do I fix the txt file not opening correctly and apprarently being compressed.

Instead of calling `openFd()`, call `open()`, to get an `InputStream` directly, and replace your `FileReader` with an `InputStreamReader` (if you really want a `Reader` interface).

Comment: That appears to have removed my error messages. Thanks a lot. I'm now not getting the expecting results but that is another hurdle cleared later on.

Comment: I m using AssetsFileDiscriptor in content provider and I have to return this AssetFileDiscriptor I cannot return InputStream ,so now what can I do?